# Any alternative mock server which can migrate from postman example?

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, postman, manjaro

there!
Our team is developing api services and use postman to test/mock.
Since the mock api is out of limits, we are searching alternative mock app/package, which can mock from existing postman examples.

We found [czardoz/postman-mock-server](https://github.com/czardoz/postman-mock-server) but it not works even if I has solved gevent problem and run with py2. (My OS is manjaro with `python3.7`.)

OS: Manjaro (ArchLinux)
lang: python
target: mock httpapi from postman examples

Answer (score 0):

We've try some repos from github and we'll implement this feature.

info:

- czardoz/postman-mock-serve
- sumory/moklr
- agilov/postmango

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone in the future looking to do this, you can use [Prism](https://github.com/stoplightio/prism).

To set it up, follow these steps:

Install it using the command:

```
npm install -g @stoplight/prism-cli
```

Next, to initiate a mock server, execute the following command:

```
prism mock <you postman collection>.json
```